# My $PATH differs from that stated in /etc/profile

Tags: linux, bash, root, path, profile

This is my entire /etc/profile.

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH

if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
  if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

According to the file, my `$PATH` should be `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` when root and `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games` if not. However, my actual `$PATH` is different.

```
daniel@debian:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
```

```
root@debian:/# echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
```

My `$PATH` is fixed to `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin` regardless of privileges and is different from what is written in `/etc/profile`. Why the discrepancy? How do I correct this issue?

Comment: `/etc/profile` is a generic default profile (single copy for all users). Your `$HOME` directory will have a hidden version (probably `.profile`) which was tailored for your user when your account was created.

Comment: Note that the script that you show also sources files under `/etc/profile.d` and may source `/etc/bash.bashrc`.  Do any of these files modify `PATH` on your system?

Answer (score -2):

The path line

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

is only valid for UID 0 which is root.

Comment: But OP shows result path for both `root` and `daniel`, and both have additional `/snap/bin`. So some additional profile exists.

Comment: `/snap/bin` is added later in `/etc/profile.d/*` somewhere - if snap is installed.

Comment: Yes this is all mentioned in the OP: *"According to the file, my $PATH should be [. . . ] when root and [. . . ] if not"*. The OP already knows that one path is being set fr root and the other for non-root users. They are asking why neither root nor their regular user actually has the PATH they expect.